# Javascript TypeError: Object Has No Method

Tags: javascript, oop

For whatever reason I'm getting `TypeError: Object #<Num> has no method 'getNumber'` when creating `numberOne` as an instance of `Num`

```
function Num(n) {
    var number = n;
    var getNumber = function() {
        return number;
    };
}

var numberOne = new Num(5);
console.log(numberOne.getNumber());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a local variable called `getNumber` without attaching it to the object.  Either give it to the object, or put it on the prototype:

```
this.getNumber = function() {
```

or

```
function Num(n) {
    this.number = n;
}

Num.prototype.getNumber = function() {
    return this.number;
}
```

If you are creating lots of objects, you probably want to put `getNumber` on the prototype so it doesn't get added to the object every single time one gets created.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring `getNumber` as a local variable inside the function. Those do not become properties of constructed objects.

Use `this`:

```
  this.getNumber = function() { ...
```

In the constructor, `this` refers to the newly-created object to be initialized.

You can also use the prototype mechanism to provide object properties.